# Multiple timelocks on wallets in contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20, openzeppelin

I am developing an ERC20 token which needs to have a timelock on a certain wallet that unlocks a certain amount of tokens every month.

I am currently using the openzeppelin function:

```
function TokenTimelock(ERC20Basic _token, address _beneficiary, uint256 _releaseTime) public
```

However, this would release all tokens at once. I want to implement something that would unlock a percentage of tokens every month, until everything is unlocked. I also need to restrict the transfer of these unlocked tokens to whitelisted addresses only, is this doable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can have an array that contains all the release Times. every time that the function `TokenTimelock` is executed you increase a counter such that it points to the next release time.

As for the whitelisted addresses, you will also have to store them in a mapping or array so that when the users execute the function to transfer the tokens to their wallets the addresses are validated before the transfer.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I just found that the open zeppelin TokenVesting.sol contract does exactly what I need without using the above token timelock.